# What git command do I need to keep a clean commit history?

Tags: git, gitlab

I’m trying to fill in for our guy who usually does all the merging into the master branch from other dev branches. He requires that we rebase our branches and squash commits before opening merge requests so that the “commit history can be clean”. This is all understandable reasoning. However, he’s AWOL and I don’t want to mess this up. This is what the current situation looks like and I want to make sure I run the right command so it stays clean.

[image]He said that last time I tried it and hit merge, it didn’t keep the history clean, so what’s the right command?

I'll reword the question once I understand what needs to be done.

Comment: It's not your fault, but if there's a specific command or procedure that should be followed in order to properly use and/or maintain an important system, it should be clearly documented. If/when the guy comes back, fully documenting that procedure should be his top priority whether he likes it or not.

Comment: If the guy who usually does the merging requires developers to squash and rebase before merging, then you should too. Sometimes rebasing creates merge conflicts, and those should be resolved by the developer. So it seems like you're asking how to squash and rebase, but it also seems like you shouldn't have to do that in your role as the substitute maintainer. Could you clarify the process as you understand it?

Comment: @Caleb, thanks for responding. I guess I have now taken over this position. And I got some clarification on how he likes it. It's now my choice as to how I like it. Although I'm a big proponent of having history so we can trace things for debugging purposes, I'm don't feel I'm experienced enough to make that call when the previous guy has more time with this and preferred rebasing over merges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you have the target branch, `master` in this case, fully up to date on your local machine

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Then switch to the branch you intend to merge into master, let's call it `feature`

```
git checkout feature
```

If you are unsure, attach a new branch to the head of `feature`and do the rebase from there, it makes it simpler (just to checkout `feature`) if something goes wrong

```
git checkout -b featureRebase
```

Do an interactive rebase on master

```
git rebase -i master
```

The rebase command will do two things

1. Find out what commits are added to the `featureRebase` branch compared to master
2. Prompt you for rearranging, and squashing commits (since the `-i` flag is specified)

When you are prompted for the rearranging and squashing, pick `squash` to squash the commits and write a new commit message.

In case you hit conflicts, solve them as you would have done in a merge and then

```
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the way he liked it